# Migration Assistant, rsync, cp and Catalina: How to copy everything in `/Users`

Tags: catalina, user-account, migration, rsync

So I just got a brand new 13" MBP and I started with the migration assistant, but it doesn't copy enough from the `~/Library` folder. For example, I'm missing my Apple Notes from that machine and missing Chrome bookmarks and my OneTab plugin and all those bookmarks.

What I want is to get a bitwise copy of the `/User/` folders onto the new machine, but when I try either `sudo cp -r` or `sudo rsync -azP` I end up with many errors and no confidence that I have a byte-for-byte copy of my previous user folders to guarantee the greatest fidelity of continuity from my previous machine. It appears that the errors I'm seeing might be related to new permissions models in OS X that prevent certain files and folders from being copied and replaced on the new machine.

I obviously know that I probably can't copy the active user without issue because of files in use, but I can't even get `rsync -azP` to work for a non-active user.

I tried recovery mode as well but rsync isn't available and `cp -r` gets errors with non-existent files (I'm also not sure if cp copies permissions correctly like rsync)

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to bypass these new OS X security and permissions controls so that I have full permission to do everything with rsync in the terminal without issue such that I have confidence I copied absolutely everything?

Comment: The new protections only apply to macOS's files, and shouldn't be applied to any user files. How did you try and transfer in the first place?

Comment: Why do you need all of /Users? Try just your profile? And if you need other profiles too, do it *as* that user. Also have you fiddled with permissions? Maybe run Disk Utility and repair permissions on your Macintosh HD.